# Open TikTok app to Its Homepage with Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I can open TikTok to a user's profile with the below code, but how do I open TikTok to its Homepage?

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://vm.tiktok.com/"+"tiktokExtension");
Intent tiktokIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
tiktokIntent.setPackage("com.zhiliaoapp.musically");
startActivity(tiktokIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

you start tiktok application this way :

```
 try{
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.zhiliaoapp.musically");
 startActivity(intent);
 }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
 //if the app doesn't exist do some stuff , like redirection to playstore.....
 }
```